# Interval class - Python

Tags: python, class, intervals

I am supposed to write a class for Intervals, then I need to define addition (how to add two intervals together). 
I've done this and it works:

```
def __add__ (self, other):
    return Interval (self.a + other.a, self.b + other.b)
```

where a and b are ending points of one interval.

Now I need to modify the code so that addition between an interval and number *c* (float or int) is defined.

[a,b] + c = [a+c,b+c] and

c + [a,b] = [a+c,b+c].

I've tried a lot of things that don't work, something like:

```
def __add__ (self, other, *args):
        if args:
            return Interval (self.a + other.a, self.b + other.b)
        else:
            return  Interval (self.a + int(number), self.b + int(number))
```

Whatever I try it doesn't work. If you have time, please take a look and give me a hint. I'd really appreciate that!

Comment: "I've done this and it works" - does your class have _all four attributes_: `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`? You only need two, actually

Comment: You're right. In my code, I define Interval1 and Interval 2, where both intervals contain two points each. That's when summing two intervals.
Problem is when adding a number (float or int) to an interval that I can't seem to figure out.

Comment: What kind of intervals are we talking about? The usual interpretation (ranges of numbers) wouldn't add in this fashion: `[a, b] + [c, d]` might only be defined if `b == c` and the result would be `[a, d]`.

Comment: Sorry, now I see that I haven't written the right thing here, so I've just changed my code.
It's about the interval analysis whose main objects are closed intervals [a,b].

Comment: `__add__` doesn't take additional arguments; it's the implementation of the use of the `+` operator, so `x + y` becomes `x.__add__(y)`. There's no way to fit additional arguments into the expression `x + y`.

Comment: First part of the code, for adding two intervals as defined works perfectly. Now since the exercise says modify your code, I thought about changing this one already written. 
In my opinion it would be easier to make new method in a class and then define how to add a number to an interval.
@chepner

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to define both `Interval(a, b) + Interval(c, d)` and `Interval(a, b) + c` (for some non-`Interval` type of `c`), you need to examine the argument `other` in the definition.

```
def __add__(self, other):
    if instanceof(other, Interval):
        return Interval(self.a + other.a, self.b + other.b)
    elif instanceof(other, (int, float)):
        return Interval(self.a + other, self.b + other)
    else:
        return NotImplemented
```

To support `c + Interval(a, b)` as well, you need to define `__radd__`:

```
def __radd__(self, other):
    return self + other
```

If you right `3 + Interval(a, b)`, `3.__add__(Interval(a, b))` doesn't know how to deal with an `Interval`, so it returns `NotImplemented`, which is Python's cue to try `Interval(a, b).__radd__(3)` instead. The definition of `__radd__` usually isn't too complicated, unless your operation isn't commutative (that is, `3 + Interval(a, b)` and `Interval(a, b) + 3` are not equal).

Comment: Thank you! In this case, operation number + Interval is commutative.

Comment: Right, sorry I meant to point that out explicitly in the last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You could assume that `other` is already an `Interval` and try the addition, but catch an exception when not:

```
def __add__ (self, other):
    try:
        return Interval (self.a + other.a, self.b + other.b)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    return  Interval (self.a + int(other), self.b + int(other))
```

If you then want to calculate `42 + x` you need the `radd` method:

```
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self + other
```